# How to fix the “No Orchestrator present at the indicated URL” error in UiPath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity, uipath-api

My system was connecting yesterday but today I am getting an Orchestrator isn’t Present at the indicated URL error.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're connecting to the right UiPath service?

If you delete the UiPath Orchestrator tenant and create a new one, the old connection won't work anymore and you'll need to reconfigure the machine code and URL in UiPath Assistant, even if you've used the same computer name in the new environment.

### UiPath Orchestrator URL

The syntax for the URL is typically this:

```
https://cloud.uipath.com/ <accountlogicalname> / <servicename>/
```

When you log into UiPath Orchestrator, it is the portion of the URL prior to the `/orchestrator_/` token. I don't feel 100% comfortable using that as a guide because UiPath could change the tokens they use in their URL tomorrow, but it's been a consistent guide for the past few years.

[image]

Double check the URL you use and the [Orchestrator isn't present](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Fix-the-Orchestrator-isnt-present-error-with-the-right-UiPath-Orchestrator-URL) error should go away.